# Task to User Story

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I am using TFS2010 and I have created a bunch of tasks. Is there any way can change Task work items to User Story?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can't easily be done.  The best option would be to copy the existing work item and then select the WI type you want there.  Afterwards, you close out the old WI.

Here is a good blog describing the process: [HowTo: Changing TFS workitem](http://juristr.com/blog/2009/08/howto-changing-tfs-workitem-type-from/)

Comment: I tried to update using the export to excel functionality, but the work item type field was read only.